# Unable to sort rows because Excel 2016 turned spreadsheet into a table. How do I change back to a spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I created a regular spreadsheet in Excel 2016. After using it for several weeks I now find that my 'sort' functionality normally accessed from the 'Data' tab does not work when selecting the entire spreadsheet. The reason for this is that it looks like Excel is now calling my entire spreadsheet a 'Table' now.

Excel has created a 'Table' tab in the ribbon, and now the entire spreadsheet seems to be classed as a table even though it still looks like a regular spreadsheet. That wouldn't be so bad because otherwise it still looks and behaves like a regular spreadsheet except for one thing: you can no longer sort the entire spreadsheet by selecting the upper left corner small cell anymore. When you select the entire sheet the 'Sort' button becomes grayed out. I'd like to be able to select the entire spreadsheet and remove the table so I can sort the entire sheet.

Question: how do I change my spreadsheet from a supposed 'table' back to a regular spreadsheet so that I can 'sort' the entire sheet under the Data tab works again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I don't have Excel 2016, I have Excel 2010, but I presume that the process will be the same.

---

When you select the table, you will see the "Design" tab for Table Tools.

In this tab there is a button called "Convert to Range". Simply click this and the table will be converted back to a normal range of cells.

[image]